# Check directory exists and if it doesnt choose an image

Tags: php

I have this code so far which perfectly but relies on there being a directory in place:

```
    $path = '/home/sites/therealbeercompany.co.uk/public_html/public/themes/trbc/images/backgrounds/'.$this->slug;
$bgimagearray = array();
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile() && !preg_match('\.jpg$/', $fileinfo->getFilename())) {
        $bgimagearray[] = "'" . $fileinfo->getFilename() . "'";
    }
}
```

I need to work in a bit at the top so that if the directory doesnt exist it defaults to the images sat in the root of the background directory...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [is_dir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php). Test your slug directory, and if it doesn't exist, use the root background directory instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function to check for the directory.

Comment: Yes, but it would provide a false positive if there were to be a file with the same name present

Answer (score 0):

Use is_dir to see if the dir is there, and if not, set $path to the current path (where the script is running from)

```
if (!is_dir($path)) {
    $path = $_SERVER["PATH_TRANSLATED"];
}
```

I very much dangerously assumed that $path is not going to be used anywhere else :)

(is_dir is better, thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

`DirectoryIterator` will throw an `UnexpectedValueException` when the path cannot be opened, so you can wrap the call into a `try/catch` block and then fallback to the root path. In a function:

```
function getBackgroundImages($path, $rootPath = NULL)
{
    $bgImages = array();
    try {
        $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($path);
        // foreach code
    } catch(UnexpectedValueException $e) {
        if($rootPath === NULL) {                
            throw $e;
        }
        $bgImages = getBackgroundImages($rootPath);
    }
    return $bgImages;
}
```

But of course `file_exists` or `is_dir` are a valid options too.